# Unwanted string formatting

Tags: python, python-requests

Very quick question. When using requests to send a PUT I am sending the following:

```
payload = {"host": "tst123:3306"}
r = requests.put(url, data=payload)
```

Requests seems to be formatting the host string so the api is receiving 'tst123%3A3306'

Is there a way to prevent this?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Comment: Have you heard of URL parameter encoding?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL-Encoding

Comment: If you add a downvote pease explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's not the params but rather the PUT data. I solved this by using instead

```
payload = json.dumps({"host": "tst123:3306"})                                 
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}                                
r = requests.put(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I can understand why the url parameters need to be encoded but why the PUT data?

Comment: This should be an edit to the original question since you're asking a new question here. Either open a new question entirely or update your original question. Also, you should read the content of the other answers since your new question was already answered.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a perfect behavior. Parameters must be encoded according to the schema

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL-Encoding
```

This is well-know best-practice since the early times of the web.

On the application side you have to decode the parameters yourself. Every programming language has modules for that. And in most cases all web-frameworks are supposed doing the decoding internally under the hood.